# Как получить слово после знака "?"

Tags: java, android

```
String = "http://rb.cafe/rbelz/sender/?name=Izzume";
```

Как мне получить слово `Izzume`?

Answer (score 4):

В общем случае можно воспользоваться классом `Uri` из пакета `android.net.Uri` (не путать с `java.net.URI`).

```
String s = "http://rb.cafe/rbelz/sender/?name=Izzume";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(s);
String paramValue = uri.getQueryParameter("name");
```

Comment: А как насчет jdk 8? Апи для этого присутствуют? не используя апи апача.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, Судя по [этому](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html), нет, в JDK8 этого нет.

Answer (score 3):

```
String result = "http://rb.cafe/rbelz/sender/?name=Izzume".split("=")[1];
```

Подробнее тут [Java - Метод split()](http://proglang.su/java/125)

Comment: при условии, что имя не содержит символ '='

Comment: В целом об этом не говорилось в задаче. Был вопрос про одну строку. Но если вдруг кому нибудь нужен парсинг URL с параметрами, то вот подробно http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection

Comment: Если взглянуть на ваш код то мы получаем, МОРЕ STRING(кучу не нужной оперативки на хранение не нужных данных, + cpu потрачено зря на создание техже множества String), + возможно не существует =, + не получаем имен.

Comment: вот, Artem Konovalov, сделал хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
String url = "http://rb.cafe/rbelz/sender/?name=Izzume";
System.out.println(url.substring(url.indexOf('=') + 1));
```

@post_zeew вариант предложил красивее конечно

Comment: Онта предложил, ваш вариант универсален, а его вариант только android...

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, В метках вопроса `android` значится не просто так.